# how to get Bank branch name by ifsc code in java web service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have only IFSC code using that IFSC code I want to get bank information like bank name, branch , address...etc

Anyone have idea, If yes than that type of process what should I do..?

Any idea please let me know..?

Comment: Could you give us an example IFSC code please, for people who have never seen one before

Comment: If you have `YourIfscCode=YESB0DNB002` then open this `https://ifsc.razorpay.com/YourIfscCode` just IFSC replace (https://ifsc.razorpay.com/YESB0DNB002) and you will get all details in Json format [Api Link here](https://github.com/razorpay/ifsc-api).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tags suggest that your are using `spring` .You should use spring's `RestTemplate` class to get detail of bank based on IFSC code.

```
String ifscCode ="XXXXXXX";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String ifscResponse = restTemplate.getForObject("http://api.techm.co.in/api/v1/ifsc/"+ifscCode, String.class);
System.out.println(ifscResponse);
```

I have used API from **api.techm.co.in**. Github link:https://github.com/mangrep/ifsc-rest-api

Comment: the api you used is free.

Comment: @Mohit , you can check razor pay API  : https://ifsc.razorpay.com/

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use a library like Unirest to make the HTTP request.

Making a request like this:

```
public class Requester {
  public static JSONObject getDetails(String code) throws UnirestException{
    return Unirest.get("https://ifsc.razorpay.com/" + code)
        .asJson().getBody().getObject();
  }

  public static void main(final String... args) throws UnirestException {
    System.out.println(getDetails("KARB0000001").toString(4));
  }
}
```

will return this:

```
{
    "BRANCH": "RTGS-HO",
    "DISTRICT": "DAKSHINA KANNADA",
    "BANK": "Karnataka Bank",
    "CONTACT": "2228222",
    "CITY": "MANGALORE",
    "ADDRESS": "REGD. & HEAD OFFICE, P.B.NO.599, MAHAVEER CIRCLE, KANKANADY, MANGALORE - 575002",
    "STATE": "KARNATAKA",
    "IFSC": "KARB0000001"
}
```

[API Docs](https://github.com/razorpay/ifsc-api)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for API everywhere but was not able to get it, So I developed API myself for banks in India, Complete documentation is available at https://github.com/kaustubhk24/Indian-Banks-Data/wiki/V1-Documentation#1--api-to-get-bank-details-using-ifsc
You can read, & Implement, it's completely free to use as hosted on GitHub